# SetWindowsHookEx 7e error

Tags: c++, hook

I'm having some troubles hooking the process to read keypresses. GetLastError gives 0x7e which means module not found, though it seems I implemented the module finding thing correctly. What I currently have (PId is process id, ThreadId is main process thread id):

```
HWND hWindow = NULL;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DWORD lpdwProcessId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &lpdwProcessId);
    if (lpdwProcessId == lParam)
    {
        hWindow = hwnd;
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK kbCallback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbdStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam);
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        if (kbdStruct.vkCode = VK_F1) {
            std::cout << "f1 was pressed" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

int main()
{
    ...

    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, initt.PId);

    HHOOK hKbdHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, kbCallback, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWindow, GWLP_HINSTANCE), initt.ThreadId);
}
```

Comment: It is a very difficult hook to get right, you must pass the handle of a DLL that can be properly injected into other processes.  A process instance is not a DLL handle.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't really get it, so instead of the window I should pass the handle of a specific DLL module of the process?

Comment: No, your DLL, one that you wrote that has the callback function.  Do use a sample project that you google somewhere to get this right.

Comment: @HansPassant It's not a DLL I'm writing, it's an external app

Comment: An App can only hook itself.  To hook and see events in other process you must write a DLL (that implements the hook procedure) and a lauching App (to install the hook). See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx